# http and https connections are kept in 'CLOSE_WAIT' if using apache camel

Tags: http, https, http-headers, apache-camel

I am using **apache-camel** as client for http and https requests.

After requests are processed the connections are going into `CLOSE_WAIT`.

My camel-context doesn't stop after the execution of requests.
If I stop it manually then connections are going into `TIME_WAIT`.

Now I am wondering if I can make connections to go into `TIME_WAIT` by some configuration in camel-context or code for http requests.

Edited:

1. I have tried solutions mentioned for this issue like adding `"Connection"` header with value `"close"`. But it didn't work.
2. I have used `HttpComponent` like below to close connections in `finally` block

Code:

```
HttpComponent httpComponent = (HttpComponent) pContext.getComponent(ServerConstants.CAMEL_COMPONENT_HTTP);
httpComponent.getHttpConnectionManager().closeIdleConnections(0);
```

Second solution is working for `http` connections but not for `https`.

Solution:

Finally able to make it work by defining custom `HeaderFilterStrategy` which does not filter `Connection`:`close` header and setting this filter bean id in `URL` as query param.

Comment: You need to add more details but on a glance this seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636316/troubleshooting-connections-stuck-in-close-wait-status

Comment: i have tried above two things.Out of which one is working for only "http".

Comment: Glad half is done now. Please check how you have configured your SSL. With given information can't help further.

Comment: It looks like few http headers(like connection) are getting filtered when we use exchange. If it is http url we are able to send those http headers to the service but when it is over https those headers are not reaching the service.

Comment: Resolved it using custom HeaderFilterStrategy.

Comment: Upvotes on useful comments/answers are deemed helpful and courteous.